# tkinter 'Tk().after()' method causing gui to not start

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to text in a textbox every  seconds. I have found several explanations on how to do this using the `Tk().after()` method. like this example

```
root = Tk()
def foo():
    print(repeat)
    root.after(5000, foo())

foo()
root.mainloop()
```

However, when trying this solution the main window never appears. It also does not exit with an exception. The only thing I can think of is that I am entering an infinite loop before reaching the `mainloop` call.

This is a condensed version of my code

```
def vp_start_gui():
    global val, w, root
    root = Tk()
    top = MainWindow (root)
    init(root, top)
    root.mainloop()

class MainWindow():
    def __init__():
        self.widgets

def init(top, gui, *args, **kwargs):
    global w, top_level, root
    w = gui
    top_level = top
    root = top
    root.after(15000,updateLoans(w, root))

def updateLoans(w, rt):
    w.LoanOfferView.insert(END, viewModel.loanOffers())
    w.LoanDemandView.insert(END, viewModel.loanDemands())
    rt.after(15000,updateLoans(rt))

vp_start_gui()
```

The `viewModel` is a third module that pulls a very small amount of data from an API. `LoanDemands is a scrolledText widget.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going wrong?

python3.4
using 'page' gui designer to develop tkinter UI

Comment: (1) Don't call `foo()`, (2) you may find it useful to read a bit about python classes and the use of `self.`

Comment: You are correct: you are entering an infinite loop, because you are calling `after` incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You need something for the program to wait for before entering infinite loop. Try this:

```
Button(root, text='start', command=foo).pack()
```

Too replace your line:

```
foo()
```

Also, you should not put parentheses when passing functions to other functions:

```
root.after(5000, foo)
```

Comment: The latter part of this answer is correct. The purpose of doing this was to update something continuously and automatically. Placing the command inside a function defeats the purpose

Comment: @RileyHugh you only have to click the button once to trigger the infinite loop. You can destroy it at the begining of `foo` (after something ugly to make sure you only do it once). Your method prints `repeat` every 5 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

So I found the answer to this problem myself.

**code example that was not working**

```
root = Tk()
def foo():
    print(repeat)
    root.after(5000, foo())

foo()
root.mainloop()
```

**code that does work for me**

```
root = Tk()
def foo():
    print(repeat)
    root.after(5000, foo)

foo()
root.mainloop()
```

After looking closer at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29619826/python-tkinter-call-event-after-every-30-seconds-or-certain-time-interval?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), [this rasperri pi forum answer](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=137597) and tkinter documentation on effbot that I quoted at the bottom. I realized that the name of the function was being referenced but the function itself is not actually called inside of the `after()` method

> Registers an alarm callback that is called after a given time.
>
> This method registers a callback function that will be called after a
>   given number of milliseconds. Tkinter only guarantees that the
>   callback will not be called earlier than that; if the system is busy,
>   the actual delay may be much longer.
>
> The callback is only called once for each call to this method. To keep
>   calling the callback, you need to reregister the callback inside
>   itself:
>
> class App:
>       def **init**(self, master):
>           self.master = master
>           self.poll() # start polling
>
> ```
> def poll(self):
>     ... do something ...
>     self.master.after(100, self.poll)
> ```